# tcpdump throws PKTAP error

Tags: tcpdump

While running tcpdump without providing any interface

`tcpdump -nS`,

I'm getting `tcpdump: cannot use data link type PKTAP` error so I tried providing the Interface option in the command

`tcpdump -i eth0` or even `eth1`

then I get the following error

`tcpdump: eth1: No such device exists`

`(BIOCSETIF failed: Device not configured)`

I even tried looking up on the Internet but i'm not getting any solution ...

Any help ??

Comment: This is presumably OS X (probably Mavericks).  Is this the tcpdump that comes with OS X, or did you build tcpdump from source?  If you built it from source, what does `tcpdump -h` print?

Comment: yes it's the tcpdump that came from Mac OSX and this is what I get when i type `tcpdump -h`
`tcpdump version 4.3.0 -- Apple version 56
libpcap version 1.5.3`

Comment: I guess it's the issue with the OS itself because when I manually installed TCPDUMP separately it works just fine ...
Any reason on why PKTAP issue is occurring ...

Answer (score 4):

I can't speak to your problem with PKTAP, but I can speak to the "No such device exists" - eth0 is a Linux-ism, and MacOS isn't Linux. You almost certainly want en0, en1, etc. "ifconfig -a" is your friend or, if you have it installed, "tshark -D".

Comment: Or `tcpdump -D`.  ("`-D`" was originally a WinDump addition to tcpdump; tcpdump picked it up from WinDump, and TShark picked it up from tcpdump.)

Answer (score 0):

> Any reason on why PKTAP issue is occurring

It's probably occurring because you installed your own version of libpcap, which does not know about the `DLT_PKTAP` link-layer header type, and Apple's tcpdump is somehow using your version rather than their own version (Apple's version *does* know about it) and, therefore, failing because, when its version of tcpdump is run without a `-i` argument, it uses an OS mechanism to capture on all devices, and that mechanism supplies packets with [`DLT_PKTAP` headers](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes/LINKTYPE_PKTAP.html) and the `DLT_PKTAP` link-layer header type.